# What happen when we call setvalueForKey in swift

Tags: swift, kvc

I have two snippet of code in below, and the second one will crash at runtime, but the first one can. Anyone know what happened there, thanks a lot?

Code Snippet 1:

```
class TestDemo:NSObject {
    var prop : Int = 0
}
var obj = TestDemo()
obj.setValue(2, forKey: "prop")
```

Code Snippet 2:

```
class TestDemo:NSObject {
    var prop : Int?
}
var obj = TestDemo()
obj.setValue(2, forKey: "prop")
```

Comment: Both code snippets compile in my Xcode 7. The second however, crashes at runtime.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrong. It's true, both of them can be compile, I test it in playground

Answer (score 1):

setValue forKey goes to your class and looks for getter methods with the key which there is none so it will look for instance variables. in the first case it finds the the var- prop since var prop:Int = 0 is a stored property with value 0

```
var prop:Int = { return 0 }()
```

But in the second case, var prop:Int? is an Int?, swift optional computed property which is not an object hence will not be checked. changing it to NSNumber will work because thats an object